# How do I Center Left-aligned Text in an Outlook Email?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, responsive-design

I'm trying to lay out a responsive email template to work across all major clients, and I'm just about there, but since Outlook doesn't support `max-width`, and I have all elements set to `width: 100%`, it's putting my content all the way to the left since it's left-aligned. I can center the header and footer with `align:center` or `margin: 0 auto`.

What can I do to prevent my content from going all the way to the left without giving anything a fixed width or using max-width (which I am using, but Outlook just ignores)?

Comment: Have you tried doing a margin-left?

Comment: Well, that wouldn't work with the responsive layout at 100% width, I don't think, since I can't give anything a fixed distance like that. If I gave it a margin of 150px so it laid out nicely in Outlook it would be all screwed up in iOS gmail or something.

Comment: Are you trying to center the body content, or just indent it? I don't quite follow what the desired effect is? Regardless, the answer to "how do I style this email" is almost always tables...

Comment: It is laid out in a table, and yes, I'd like the body content to be centered without giving it a fixed width, and without centering the text (keeping it left -aligned)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are referring more to a "fluid" layout (basing off percentage) rather than a "responsive" one (where you would use media queries to specify styles based on width of display device).

Since setting a `pixel` value for the `margin-left` wouldn't make a lot of sense, why not set the `margin-left` to a `percentage` value?

```
margin-left: 4%;
```

Otherwise, you might want to take a look at the following resource found on MailChimp regarding media queries.

http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/media-queries/

Comment: Well, I was just experimenting with media-queries again, and I think the issue that comes up then, is that to use a media-query you need style in the `<head></head>` but Gmail doesn't play with that, so for any elements that require styling, it needs to be done both inline and in the head (since some clients don't like inline), and  the inline over-writes the media-query class it looks like from my tests, even with `!important` on the class in the `<head>`.

Comment: As for percentage, it would be the same problem as pixels, though less extreme, since it's laying out differently in different email clients (those that accept max-width center it correctly) and it would just be pushed over too far from the left then for some.

Comment: Responsive (media queries) doesn't work in Gmail but fluid does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and use media queries to adjust the width percentages at different screen sizes if needed. Just keep in mind that your media queries won't take effect in [these email clients](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/).

```
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#252525">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="10%">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="left" width="80%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            &nbsp;<br>content<br>...<br>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td width="10%">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```