# Are there any practical reasons to not build a responsive email for Gmail first?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, gmail

Having ranged through a number of [support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) [indices](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/css-in-html-email) and [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149731/how-do-i-center-left-aligned-text-in-an-outlook-email) - [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388779/is-there-a-method-of-turning-off-the-gmail-apps-auto-resize-feature-in-an-email) - [shooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383921/how-to-solve-a-fluid-email-layout-with-a-top-right-floating-div-which-should-the), [templates](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/) and [tutorials](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/responsive-html-email-design/), I felt like I was struck by a thunderbolt when it occurred to me that I should be making all my emails to work in Gmail first, because I don't recall at least ever seeing that as a specific recommendation.

This is assuming I have elements I may want to be visible depending on the user's device/screen, and as such, out of all the email clients I've been hassled by, Gmail is the least flexible since it doesn't support any embedded styles. So, to me, it would make the most sense to layout the email for how it should work in Gmail, then add on to it from there primarily with embedded styles.

As per the question guidelines, I'm not looking for opinions about this, but technical limitations that you all could foresee arising as a result of this workflow. That being said, what would they be, if any?

Comment: Since I'm both specifically and explicitly asking only for technical limitations that might arise from building first in Gmail, I don't understand where the issue of opinion would come into this. I agree that this workflow and it's use would be a matter of opinion, but that's not what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I've been slicing emails for a very long time and have watched the changes (or lack thereof) over the years. I don't think in terms of "GMail" or "Outlook" first but rather what I consider the three basic categories of HTML emails: fixed, fluid or responsive (or a combo of one of the first two and responsive, too).

A properly done fixed email looks the same everywhere and is supported by every major email client. A fluid email will change on every email client but the changes will be relative to neighboring changes and can for the most part be predicted. A responsive email, although similar to a fluid email, has much more granular control over rendering and can actually set the "fluid rules" based on screen size.

Depending on your target audience, my recommendation to you would be to build a fixed email that looks awesome (you're worst case scenario) and then add styles to the `<body>` tag to handle responsive to make it even more awesome. Once you get the knack for building fixed emails it goes pretty fast so you'll spend most of your time in the responsive side of things.

Answer (score 0):

View [Campaign Monitor's Guide to CSS](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for the most comprehensive guide of supported CSS in email clients. In general, before you use a certain type of css you should see what email clients are supported. Gmail would be a good reference point to start, but you will want to be aware that there are some elements that will not work in some other clients.

Comment: I did actually link that in my question, but the practical crux of my question rests on the fact Gmail, as indicated on the page we have now both linked, is alone in not supporting `<style>` which is why it seems to me a logical choice for where to start as the clear (but still significantly large) outlier.

Comment: Sorry, that was a visited link for me in your write-up (which is very close in color to regular text) so I didn't see it. I use the workflow that you suggested and it works well for me. Sometimes it means more (and confusing) code, but I haven't really run into any technical limitations.